# Search into Windows registry with grep/cygwin

Tags: windows-registry, cygwin, grep

I'm trying to search and remove unrelevantregistry keys, and it sounds like Cygwin does allow access to them through `/proc/registry`.

However, recursive `grep -r` (2.21) outputs error lines like :

```
grep: /proc/registry/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.aspx/@: Is a directory
```

Strange error for a recursive grep. Then, file displays :

```
$ file /proc/registry/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.aspx/@
/proc/registry/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.aspx/@: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

So it's a file now. I used `cat`.

```
$ cat /proc/registry/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.aspx/@
VisualStudio.aspx.10.0
```

And I can't `cd` into it, moreover `ls -l` doesn't display the `d` flags. Why `grep` still considers it as being a directory ?

Comment: Using cygwin to edit the registry seems a bit risky. It can mess up file permissions and ownership etc. so I don't know what this might do to registry files.
Is there some reason why the regular regedit utility won't do what you need?

Comment: `regedit`’s search capabilities are rather limited. That being said, this is an interesting issue, especially since `find -type f` works as expected.

Comment: Hmm. What is the `@` supposed to represent? `cd /proc/registry/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.aspx` followed by `ls` works for me.

Comment: What is the exact `grep` command you are using?

Comment: @DavidPostill : `grep -r string /proc/registry`. Updated my question to added the version. Also `cd /proc/.../.aspx` then `ls` shows `@` among other entries.

Comment: What "string" are you searching for? I'm trying to reproduce  your issue :/

Comment: @DavidPostill A custom one... `tmp-build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understamding is that cygwin's registry support is somewhat experimental. You're not looking at regular files and folders, but rather a kind of simulated directory structure. I'd be very surprised if utilities like grep would behave correctly in there.

You'd likely have a lot more success with powershell, and it won't have any of the limitations of regedit.